# ¿Cómo listar registros que contengan una misma fecha?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Soy novato en Postgresql,
Quisiera saber como listar las tareas que tuvieran una misma fecha y que solo muestre las fechas que tengan mas de una tarea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el query que tengo hasta ahora, solo muestra la cantidad:

```
SELECT COUNT(T.tarea),T.date FROM TABLA T GROUP BY T.date HAVING COUNT(T.tarea)>=2
```

Comment: Listo, realizado

Comment: Te falta hacer el select de la columna de tarea...

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada, obtenemos por tarea y fecha la cantidad de filas de cada grupo de las columnas mencionadas, pero solo aquellos que eventualmente tengan más de una fila (más de una fecha):

```
SELECT tarea, 
       date,
       COUNT(1) as Cant
       FROM TABLA
       GROUP BY tarea, date 
       HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Luego, mediante una subconsulta, obtenemos las filas que entran dentro del conjunto anterior:

```
SELECT T.*
       FROM TABLA T 
       INNER JOIN (
           SELECT tarea, 
                  date
                  FROM TABLA
                  GROUP BY tarea, date 
                  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) G
       ON G.tarea = T.tarea
       AND G.date = T.date
```